# Wrong date in workflow email

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I am using a workflow for a calendar. In workflow email I use `[%Current List:Start Time%]` and `[%Current List:End Time%]` for the events. But the date is always displayed as "Monday, January, 01, 0001".

How to fix this? How to insert a specific column from a list to insert in a workflow email?

Comment: It should be current item:start time and current item:end time, where are you getting those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is related to that these fields are empty. If you want to use Start and End time of the item workflow is started on, you should use Data Source = "Current Item" instead of "Current List" and it should work.

Comment: @MikhaliSP but it did not work for start time. But end time works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the Start Time field is filled at the time the email is sent? Try to add the log activity with this field to make sure that it is not empty

Comment: How to add log activity with the field?

Comment: Just place cursor before email activity and start typying "log". Then press Enter (Log activity adds), press underlined word "Message", and button "...". After that in the String Builder press Add Lookup and select Current Item/Start Time. Press ok. After republishing and runing WF, in workflow history Start Time value will be shown.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. I added the start time log before the email. But it still shows that 0001 date.

Comment: So, that means that at the moment of sending email this field (Start Time) is not set yet. So, the problem is somewhere before. You should analize why this field is not set yet.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Check This Different Formats Working fine.

Output is Short Date 5/1/2013   String 5/1/2013 11:00:00 AM long date  Wednesday, May 01, 2013.